Problems with bibliography in article class
I have a problem with the references in this latex document:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[inner=1in,outer=1in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{XXXX}
\rhead{October 2024}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            allcolors  = blue, % default color
            urlcolor=black
            ]{hyperref}          

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\bf {\large Letter}}
\end{center}

\noindent Dear XXX, \cite{abcd}  does this and that.
        
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliography}
    
\end{document}

This is an entry in the bib file:
@article{abcd,
    title={AAA},
    author={BBB},
    journal={Journal},
    year={2024}
}

This is a screenshot of the pdf:

I don't like (edited in red):

The square parenthesis in the citation call-out: "[BBB, 2024]". I would like "(BBB, 2024)".

The fact that "[BBB, 2024]" is repeated in the formatted bibliographic reference. I would like to omit "[BBB, 2024]" from the formatted entry.


Could you advise on how to do that?

The BBB isn't really repeated, if you have a real name the  as author the cite key would be an abbreviated form and the bibliography entry would have the cite key and full name, it's just they are both BBB here

Thanks. Perhaps my question was unclear. See now the screenshot, where I have deleted in red the undesired part

Yes but that is needed the cite key has an abbreviated name, and then the entry has to have that abbreviation and the full name. It only looks odd here as you have a fake name bbb that can not be abbreviated

Add the instruction \usepackage[round]{natbib} and run a full recompile cycle.

@Mico Super, that works, thanks

If you want to keep using the apalike bibliography style along with BibTeX,  I suggest you add the instruction
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

in the preamble and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

It seems, simply apalike is not really what you want. I guess you want an author-year style, e.g., using biblatex:
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{abcd,
    title={AAA},
    author={BBB},
    journal={Journal},
    year={2024}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[inner=1in,outer=1in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{XXXX}
\rhead{October 2024}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            allcolors  = blue, % default color
            linkcolor=blue,
            urlcolor=black
            ]{hyperref}          

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\bf {\large Letter}}% Recommended change: \large\textbf{Letter}
\end{center}

\noindent Dear XXX, \parencite{abcd}  does this and that.
   
\printbibliography

\end{document}


or using natbib:
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{abcd,
    title={AAA},
    author={BBB},
    journal={Journal},
    year={2024}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[inner=1in,outer=1in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{XXXX}
\rhead{October 2024}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            allcolors  = blue, % default color
            linkcolor=blue,
            urlcolor=black
            ]{hyperref}          

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\bf {\large Letter}}% Recommended change: \large\textbf{Letter}
\end{center}

\noindent Dear XXX, \cite{abcd}  does this and that.
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}


